# Buy licenses for MonoTouch and MonoDroid together

Tags: xamarin.ios, license-key, xamarin.android

Is it possible to get both the MonoTouch and MonoDroid licenses in sort of a package deal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MonoDroid is still in very early beta.  No licensing or pricing details have been announced.

Comment: If you sign up for the beta you can test the software, though I'm not sure if applications have closed now.

Answer (score 1):

As of Apr 16th 2011 the website says that having a monotouch license gives you 50% off monodroid 1.0